# jquery ajax jsonp cross domain callback function dont get any data only in IE7 and below

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, cross-domain, jsonp, jquery-callback

I have two servers, one is localhost:3000, the other is gjy.com:3001,

gjy.com:3301 server side is expressjs.

```
//app.js
app.get('/user/jsonp', user.jsonp);

//user.js
exports.jsonp = function(req, res) {
    res.jsonp({"name": "jsp"});
};
```

localhost:3000 the page JS function code is like below:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://gjy.com:3001/user/jsonp',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('data is loaded');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log('err');
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

and the console result in ie7 and below is

```
data is loaded
undefined
```

but the console result in other browsers

```
data is loaded
{"name": "jsp"}
```

Comment: It's odd that you are setting the `crossDomain` option to true with a `dataType` of JSONP.  This shouldn't be needed, and perhaps is causing your issue.  I suggest removing the `crossDomain` option and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

In IE8 Microsoft implemented their own version of crossDomain, and rather than implementing the CORS version of XMLHttpRequest, the IE team went with their own propriety object, named [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505%28VS.85%29.aspx).

jQuery patches this for IE8, but in IE7 there is no such method implented, so IE7 simply does not support cross domain calls, it's only supported in IE8 and up.

Comment: jquery ajax do support ie7 crossdomain request! but not support console function